# How to compare attributes of a d3 chart with if ... else statement?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The attribute below (`dataset1`) either loads or does not, depending on the user's action

```
chart.select(".line")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", dataset1)
```

Later on I need to check whether it loaded or not using an `if`...`else` statement. I am trying to do the following, but it doesn't work:

```
if (chart.select(".line").attr("d") == dataset1) {
...
} else {
... }
```

What am I doing wrong?
When I try to `console.log(dataset1);` it gives me out

```
t(t){function a(){c.push("M",i(n(s),o))}for(var l,c=[],s= [],f=-1,h=t.length,g=En(e),p=En(r);++f<h;)u.call(this,l=t[f],f)?s.push([+g.call(this,l,f),+p.call(this,l,f)]):s.length&&(a(),s=[]);ret…
```

Edit: Here is what `colsole.log(chart.select(".line").attr("d"));` looks like:

`M0,140.165L30,160.20233333333334L60,170.33433333333335L90,181.08399999999997L120,193.27300000000005L150,208.15366666666665L180,215.26533333333333L210,214.10366666666667L240,216.39299999999997L270,224.587L300,224.18466666666666L330,227.68100000000004L360,231.79500000000002L390,224.4056666666667L420,248.132L450,235.858L480,215.186`

Comment: is that all it logs ?

Comment: what is your original input for dataset1? The same thing you get in the `console.log()` ?

Comment: @KWeiss Not really. They are some CSV float numbers like 0.01093 0.06624 0.07641 0.09341. I am trying to compare those numbers, but I think they might be changed into path values somewhere along or even into something more complex